# Show that $f(y)-f(x)=\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{d}{dt}(f(\gamma(t)))dt}$ on a manifold.

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

If $f$ is a smooth function in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, we have $$f(y)-f(x)=\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{d}{dt}(f(x+t(y-x))dt}=\int_{0}^{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\frac{\partial f(x+t(y-x))}{\partial (y_i-x_i)}\frac{d(t(y_i-x_i))}{dt}}dt}=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(y_i-x_i)\cdot \frac{\partial f(x+t(y-x))}{\partial(y_i-x_i)}}dt}$$

Now if I try to do something similar on a n-dimensional riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$ and a geodesic $\gamma:[0,1]\to M$, with $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\gamma(1)=y$, then $$f(y)-f(x)=\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{d}{dt}(f(\gamma(t)))dt}$$
So, (I suppose that) we have $\frac{d}{dt}f(\gamma(t))=g(\gamma(t))(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} f(\gamma),\dot{\gamma}(t))$ But I'm really confuse with this, cause I need some chart or not?

Comment: just to clarify: are you asking why the integral formula is true, or how to differentiate $\dfrac{d}{dt}f(\gamma(t))$ using chain rule? If it's the latter then you can write it as $df_{\gamma(t)}[\dot{\gamma}(t)]$. If you want to express this in terms of a chart then you can write this as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(\gamma(t)) \cdot \dot{\gamma}^i(t)$ (where $\gamma^i:=x^i\circ \gamma$ is the $i^{th}$ component of the curve $\gamma$ with respect to the chart)

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks! I was just looking for the same way to write the above in a manifold. So $f(y)-f(x)=\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(\gamma(t))\cdot \gamma'^i(t)}$ where we use the eisentein notation for the sum of index. But this product is the same as $g(\gamma(t))(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(\gamma(t)),\gamma'^i(t))$?

Comment: Yes, using summation convention. No, for this formula you do not need the metric, and what you've written doesn't make sense because $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(\gamma(t))$ and $\dot{\gamma}^i(t)$ are numbers, not vectors in $T_{\gamma(t)}M$.

Comment: But if $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$ and let $p=dist_{M}(x,y)$. If $c(t)$ is the geodesic curve connecting $x=c(0)$ and $y=c(l)$, then $f(y)=f(x)+\int_{0}^{p}{df(c'(t))dt}=f(x)+\int_{0}^{p}{\langle\nabla f(c(t)),c'(t)\rangle dt}$, cause the gradient $\nabla f(x)$ is a vector in the tangent space and if $v\in T_{x}M$, then $df(v)=\langle\nabla f(x),v\rangle_{M}$, so, I misunderstand something?

Comment: Yes, it's true that $df_{c(t)}[c'(t)] = g_{c(t)}[\text{grad} f (c(t)), c'(t)]$ (simply because $\text{grad}(f)$ is defined as the vector field which "corresponds" to the 1-form $df$ under the muscial isomorphism of $g$), but I don't see why you'd want to unnecessarily introduce a Riemannian metric, because the chain rule for calculating $(f\circ c)'(t) = df_{c(t)}[c'(t)]$ doesn't even need a metric.

Answer (score 1):

As one of the comments on this post has indicated, there is no need to introduce a Riemannian metric to this smooth manifold in order to prove the identity in question. It follows directly from the chain rule and fundamental theorem of calculus on $\mathbb{R}$. Given a curve on your manifold $\gamma: [0,1] \rightarrow M$ where $\gamma(0) = x$ and $\gamma(1) = y$ and a smooth function $f:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we see that:
$$f(y) - f(x) = (f\circ\gamma)(1) - (f\circ\gamma)(0) =  \int_0^1 (f\circ\gamma)'(t)dt.$$

In fact, this equality is true for any once differentiable path (not just a geodesic) on your manifold from $x$ to $y$, and thus is a path independent identity.